# How to use method Events: list to get events with specified created time or update time with google-calendar-api?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I use method `Events: list` of google-calendar-api to get events on the specified calendar at this [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?authuser=1).

I found these parameters：

> calendarId,iCalUID,maxAttendees,maxResults,orderBy,pageToken,privateExtendedProperty,q,sharedExtendedProperty,showDeleted,showHiddenInvitations,singleEvents,syncToken,timeMax,timeMin,timeZone,updatedMin

But when I use `updatedMin='2019-01-16T00:00:00+09:00'`,I can only get data that was created or updated later than this time.

In fact,I want to get `created time` or `updated time` of events between `'2019-01-16T00:00:00+09:00'` and `'2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00'`.

What should I do?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is what you want, how about giving ``2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00`` to ``timeMax`` like ``timeMax=2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00`` and/or ``timeMax=2019-01-16T23%3A59%3A59%2B09%3A00``? If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: I think timeMax is `Upper bound (exclusive) for an event's start time ` as the document said.

Comment: The result retrieved by ``timeMax=2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00&updatedMin=2019-01-16T16:00:00+09:00`` was not what you want. I understood like this. So I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Anyway, I still appreciate your answer.

Comment: @Tanaike I think I can use updatedMin to do what I want.
For example, when I use `updatedMin='2019-01-16T16:00:00+09:00'`,I can only get data that was created or updated later than this time.
In the response,I remove the events data over `'2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00'`.

Then I can get created time or updated time of events between `'2019-01-16T00:00:00+09:00'` and `'2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00'`.

Am I right?

Comment: I couldn't understand about ``Then I can get created time or updated time of events between '2019-01-16T00:00:00+09:00' and '2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00'.``. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. I think that your consideration is correct. Because the events data over '2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00' were removed, there are no data of after that.

Comment: Hi,if today is 2019-01-25,that means when I use updatedMin='2019-01-16T00:00:00+09:00',I can get the events data created time or updated time of events from '2019-01-16T00:00:00+09:00' to current time(2019-01-25),then I remove the created time or updated time of events data over '2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00'.So the events created time or updated time of events between '2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00' and current time(2019-01-25) will be remove

Comment: Thank you for your additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following attempt:

For example,today is 2019-01-25,that means when I use `updatedMin='2019-01-16T00:00:00+09:00'`,I can get the events data created time or updated time of events from `'2019-01-16T00:00:00+09:00'` to current time(2019-01-25),then I remove the created time or updated time of events data over `'2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00'`.

So the events created time or updated time of events between `'2019-01-16T23:59:59+09:00'` and current time(2019-01-25) will be remove.

After this attempt, I checked the data and found that my logic was correct.